# Get email templates defined in admin panel in custom module

Tags: magento2, admin, email-templates, customer-emails

I'm writing a module that sends some emails to customers. 
Right now it works just fine with the email template defined in my code. Thing is I want other non-developer users to be able to access that template in the admin-panel.

Is there a way I could define a **template** in the back-office and call it in my  code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create email template configuration at stores > configuration like below in app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="paytrade" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="general" translate="label" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="paytrade_commission_template" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
                    <label>Test Tab Email Template</label>
                    <comment>Test tab email sent to xyz.</comment>        
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

your email_templates.xml file as below at app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="paytrade_general_paytrade_commission_template" label="Test Tab Email Template" file="test_tab_template_email.html" type="html" module="Ewall_Paytrade" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Now your email template php code like below:

```
<?php
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Helper;

/**
 * Custom Module Email helper
 */
class Email extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD  = 'paytrade/general/paytrade_commission_template';
    /* Here section and group refer to name of section and group where you create this field in configuration*/

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface
     */
    protected $inlineTranslation;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var string
    */
    protected $temp_id;

    /**
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    * @param Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation
    * @param Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $context;
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder; 
    }

    /**
     * Return store configuration value of your template field that which id you set for template
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getConfigValue($path, $storeId)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $path,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $storeId
        );
    }

    /**
     * Return store 
     *
     * @return Store
     */
    public function getStore()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore();
    }

    /**
     * Return template id according to store
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTemplateId($xmlPath)
    {
        return $this->getConfigValue($xmlPath, $this->getStore()->getStoreId());
    }

    /**
     * [generateTemplate description]  with template file and tempaltes variables values                
     * @param  Mixed $emailTemplateVariables 
     * @param  Mixed $senderInfo             
     * @param  Mixed $receiverInfo           
     * @return void
     */
    public function generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo)
    {
        $template =  $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->temp_id)
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, /* here you can defile area and
                                                                                 store of template for which you prepare it */
                        'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
                ->setFrom($senderInfo)
                ->addTo($receiverInfo['email'],$receiverInfo['name']);
        return $this;        
    }

    /**
     * [sendInvoicedOrderEmail description]                  
     * @param  Mixed $emailTemplateVariables 
     * @param  Mixed $senderInfo             
     * @param  Mixed $receiverInfo           
     * @return void
     */
    /* your send mail method*/
    public function yourCustomMailSendMethod($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo)
    {

        $this->temp_id = $this->getTemplateId(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_FIELD);
        $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();    
        $this->generateTemplate($emailTemplateVariables,$senderInfo,$receiverInfo);    
        $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();        
        $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
    }

}
```

After completing above steps, you can create new email template from **Marketing > Communications > Email Templates**

Click on new email template > Select above created email template from dropdown > click on load template > save email template

Go to store > configuration  and Test Tab Email Template field value set new created email template from above step

Comment: Do I have to repeat this process for each template ?

Comment: Yes for each custom template